# Getting 404 on valid subdomain pages when refreshing

Tags: vue.js, dns, http-status-code-404

I have a site on a subdomain, `staging.mysite.com` and I'm get a 404 for any and all pages when I refresh that URL. This is to say I can navigate from the app root to any page and it loads fine, but if I then refresh that page, I get a 404.

I'm thinking it might be a DNS issue?

`mysite.com` is hosted on Godaddy and is my account's primary domain. I have an A record for `staging` pointing to my hosting IP and I have added `staging` as a subdomain with the domain as `staging.mysite.com` and document root as `public_html/staging`.

There is no problem when I'm developing on my localhost, only when I deploy to the staging site. This leads me to believe it is not a VueJS routing problem.

Is this a DNS configuration error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated the .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Additional info
[Example Server Configurations](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: Thank you kindly. That did the trick. I didn't have an htaccess file in that root.